# Is this an acceptable way to use a StateManager in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

The code (in CoffeeScript) pasted below works, but I am not entirely sure it's the "right" way to do something in ember.js. The idea is a person is editing his/her info. The info has different screens that can be navigated between.

It particular, what concerns me is that I need to create the StateManager in a didInsertElement event, instead of creating it as an attribute of the main view. Otherwise, it does not render.

Any feedback is grately appreciated

```
window.App.PersonBioView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName : "app_templates_person_bio"

window.App.PersonNameView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName : "app_templates_person_name"

window.App.PersonMainView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName : "app_templates_person_main"
    showName : -> 
        this.subViewManager.goToState 'nameView'
    showBio : -> 
        this.subViewManager.goToState 'bioView'
    didInsertElement : -> 
        this.subViewManager = Ember.StateManager.create
            initialState : 'nameView'
            rootElement : "#content"
            nameView : Ember.ViewState.create
                    view : window.App.PersonNameView.create
                            person : this.person
            bioView : Ember.ViewState.create
                    view : window.App.PersonBioView.create
                            person : this.person

window.App.PersonController.mainView = window.App.PersonMainView.create
        person :  window.App.Person.create
            firstName : "John"
            lastName : "Doe" 
            hobbies : ''

window.App.PersonController.mainView.append()
```

Comment: First off, you don't need to keep using `window` all over the place. Once you create something using `window` you can just refer to it e.g. `window.myThing = "moo"; console.log(myThing)`